# Warning: Prop `className` did not match. when using @font-face and styled-components with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, font-face, styled-components

[image]

Hi all, I have created a GlobalStyle which I call my fonts using font-face.

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';

export const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
  html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: url("/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: url("/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
  font-style: bold;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
}
`;
```

This `GlobalStyle` is called inside my `_app.tsx` file. Fonts are located in my `public` folder.

I never had this error but after I added `@font-face` this issue started.

What I have tried:

adding this code to `.babelrc`:

```
"plugins": [["styled-components", { "ssr": true }]]
```

Installed `babel-preset-next` and `babel-plugin-styled-components` extensions.

Nothing worked.
What I'm doing wrong?

styled-components version: 5.3.0
next: 11.0.1

Comment: Try removing `reactStrictMode: true` from `next.config.json`. Also, is this occurring on production build also `next build && next start`?

Comment: @brc-dd changing strict mode to false did not help :( and btw, it dont happens in production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed creating a _document.tsx file in pages folder.

```
import Document from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx: any) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: (App: any) => (props: any) =>
            sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
        });

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      };
    } finally {
      sheet.seal();
    }
  }
}
```